# How do I enable tooltips on a disabled text-field in vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

The code shows the tooltip icon but does not show anything when I hover on it.How do I enable it on hover like in the case of number below.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips

```
<v-text-field label="Name" id="name" disabled>
    <v-tooltip slot="append" :value="true" bottom>
        <v-icon slot="activator" color="primary" dark>live_help</v-icon>
        <span>Name of the user</span>
    </v-tooltip>
</v-text-field>

<v-text-field label="number" id="number">
     <v-tooltip slot="append" bottom>
          <v-icon slot="activator" color="primary" dark>live_help</v-icon>
          <span> Number of years</span>
     </v-tooltip>
</v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vuetify disables all pointer events for disabled input fields:

```
.v-input--is-disabled:not(.v-input--is-readonly) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Two ways to remove this:

1. You add a custom class to this input where you say `pointer-events: auto` or
2. You pass the `readonly` prop to the component so that Vuetify adds `v-input--is-readonly` class which removes the `pointer-events: none` condition automatically.

So, your input definition becomes:

```
<v-text-field label="Name" id="name" disabled readonly>
    <v-tooltip slot="append" :value="true" bottom>
        <v-icon slot="activator" color="primary" dark>live_help</v-icon>
        <span>Name of the user</span>
    </v-tooltip>
</v-text-field>
```