# Display Vuetify tooltip on disabled button

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I am having difficulty displaying a tooltip on a button that is disabled with Vuetify.

I've made sure the tooltip can be displayed when the button is enabled, this works as expected. I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826891/how-do-i-enable-tooltips-on-a-disabled-text-field-in-vuetify) is related, but I'm not well-versed enough to know if this applies to a `v-btn`. I attempted to create a custom class and add that to the specific `v-btn` element but I did not have any luck.

## Example HTML

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid class="text-xs-center">
      <v-layout
        flex
        justify-space-between
        row
        wrap
      >
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-btn @click="show = !show">toggle</v-btn>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex xs12 class="mt-5">
          <v-tooltip v-model="show" top>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn disabled icon v-on="on">
                <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">shopping_cart</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Programmatic tooltip</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

## Example JavaScript

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZNqpOW?editors=1010

I'm expecting that the tooltip can be displayed when hovering over a disabled button. I'm hoping to use this to explain why the button is disabled.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Not sure if this is the absolute best way but I was able to get a tooltip on a disabled button by wrapping it in a `div` tag:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYBbJV?editors=1010)

```html
<v-tooltip v-model="show" top>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <div v-on="on">
      <v-btn disabled icon>
        <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">shopping_cart</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  </template>
  <span>Programmatic tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: I had to wrap mine into a <span> instead of a <div> because it wasn't positioned in the right place. Cheers

Answer (score 29):

As vuetify tooltip evolved to the slot syntax the right solution ist now this one:

```
<v-tooltip bottom :disabled="valid">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <div v-on="on" class="d-inline-block">
        <v-btn color="primary" :disabled="!valid">Button</v-btn>
    </div>
    </template>
    <span>You must accept first</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: the best answer for me!

Answer (score 4):

building on Hexodus' answer, this would be the solution for Vuetify 3:

```
    <v-tooltip bottom :disabled="valid">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <div v-bind="props" class="d-inline-block">
                <v-btn color="primary" :disabled="!valid">Button</v-btn>
            </div>
        </template>
        <span>You must accept first</span>
    </v-tooltip>
```